# MySQL InnoDB Hangs after few thousand inserts

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, innodb

I am using MySQL v5.6.24 on linux mint, I am trying to insert 1 Million rows in a table. It has only username and email fields. I configured mysql as follows:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2GB
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

This is on my local machine (i5-4Gb ram). Everytime I run the script, it inserts few hundred rows, then just hangs and eats up the cpu upto 100%.

Also I am using Node to insert these rows.

```
var post={
        name: nameData ,
        email : emailData
    };

connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post, function(error,info){
    if(error){

        console.log(error.message);
    }else{
    //console.log('u '+totalUsers);
    console.log(info.insertId);

    }
});
```

Please guide me how to optimize this.

Comment: I always lump my large inserts into INSERT (vars) VALUES(vals),(vals),(vals)... and then make sure that there are only about 1000 (vals) added per query.

Comment: How cheap, in terms of code changes, do want the working code to be? Wrap it in a 'loop of 'transactions'. You don't change your current query. You just 'wrap it' in a 'transaction loop'. I suggest a 'commit' every '500' records initially. I expect it to complete. If not then try 100 records at a time. If this doesn't work then there are other issues.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G` is possibly too big for a 4GB machines.  Recommend no more than `1500M`.  Swapping is very bad for performance.

Comment: None of the comments (so far) explain the CPU hang, but any of them _may_ make the problem "go away".

Comment: @RickJames, You are correct. To setup a machine for 'good throughput' then a need to know a lot of technical information be available. However, by default, databases and 'operating systems' are setup to be 'generous' and work effectively under 'normal conditions'. It is what happens when the 'machine' gets 'over-committed' that is 'awkward'. Unless there is access to that 'technical data' then all we can do is suggest methods of 'avoiding' being 'over committed'. Hence the advice.

Comment: What was the value of `autocommit`?